# x86 memory[si] vs [bx+si]

Tags: assembly, x86

What's the difference between the 3 array indexing methods

```
mov  si, INDEX
mov  ax,  memory[si]
```

and

```
mov  bx, offset  memory
mov  si, INDEX
mov  ax,  [bx+si]
```

and

```
lea  bx,  memory
mov  si,  INDEX
mov  ax,  [bx+si]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all do the same thing when shown as you did. You have seen this. But they way they fit into the code around is what's really different.

In all three you can increment SI to reference all the values in adjacent array elements.

In 2 and 3 you can bump BX by a fixed amount at the end of an outer loop to jump to the next row of a 2D array. The inner loop is bumping SI by the size of the array elements (1, 2, 4, etc) to do something with the current row.

1 is shorter if you need to save space and have a 1D array. Or maybe you are out of registers and need BX to hold something you are calculating so you need to not use BX.

3 is handy mostly when you have a more complicated part to the right of the comma.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between 2 and 3 in terms of performance or applicability.  #1 is more direct and efficient, but not as dynamic as 2 and 3.

Comment: @annoying_squid can you please give me a reference where i can find that it's more efficient than the other 2 ?

Comment: @Belbesy I can't give any references for this.  But when I assembled each I found #1 to consist of 7 bytes, #2 to be 8 bytes, and #3 to be 9 bytes.  You may find something else since it's part of your code.